# Unable to run a python package in Arcgis notebook (GIS)

Tags: python, arcgis, esri

I'm trying to run a python visualization package (Altair) in Arcgis notebook and I'm getting this error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [1]:
Line 17:    color='z:Q'

RuntimeError: make_tuple(): unable to convert arguments to Python object (compile in debug mode for details)
```

Here is my code:

```
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Compute x^2 + y^2 across a 2D grid
x, y = np.meshgrid(range(-5, 5), range(-5, 5))
z = x ** 2 + y ** 2

# Convert this grid to columnar data expected by Altair
source = pd.DataFrame({'x': x.ravel(),
                     'y': y.ravel(),
                     'z': z.ravel()})

alt.Chart(source).mark_rect().encode(
    x='x:O',
    y='y:O',
    color='z:Q'
)
```